# Setting minimum frame delay for gifs

Tags: c#, delay, frame

I'm displaying some gifs in my c# .net program using PictureBox controls.
I want to emulate the way browsers like chrome, firefox, etc set a minimum frame delay for their gifs. 
There's one gif that has 0 framedelay and shows up really fast in my program, but slower in browser because the browser sets the delay.

I'm getting the frame delay rate with this code, but I don't know how to set it.

```
   PropertyItem item = img.GetPropertyItem(0x5100);
```

The only answers I've found online haven't been very detailed, and just say "ignore the framerate" without telling me much. Is there a way to make a copy of my gif and explicitly set the frame delay property without saving the image? The nature of the program is dynamic, so the gifs in question may be anything and it has to be flexible so I can't just change the frame delay once.

Edit: I can only think of having to go into the binary file of the gif itself and changing it there, but this seems like a much more complicated solution to the relatively simple problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the simplest approach would be to write your own mini-player:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private AnimatedGif _animatedGif;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _animatedGif = new AnimatedGif(@"..\..\playing-cards.gif");
        }

        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var animatedGif = _animatedGif;
                var frames = animatedGif.Frames;
                for (var i = 0; i < frames; i++)
                {
                    var image = animatedGif.GetFrame(i);
                    pictureBox1.Image = image;
                    var millisecondsTimeout = animatedGif.Durations[i] * 10;
                    Thread.Sleep(millisecondsTimeout);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    internal class AnimatedGif
    {
        public AnimatedGif(string filename)
        {
            if (filename == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("filename");

            var image = Image.FromFile(filename);

            var item = image.PropertyItems.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Id == 0x5100);
            if (item == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("filename");

            var frames = item.Value.Length / 4;
            var durations = new int[frames];
            for (var i = 0; i < frames; i++)
            {
                durations[i] = BitConverter.ToInt32(item.Value, i * 4);
            }

            Frames = frames;
            Durations = durations;
            Image = image;
        }

        public Image Image { get; set; }
        public int Frames { get; set; }
        public int[] Durations { get; set; }

        public Image GetFrame(int index)
        {
            var activeFrame = Image.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Time, index);
            if (activeFrame != 0) return null;
            var bitmap = new Bitmap(Image);
            return bitmap;
        }
    }
}
```

Then improve it by accounting for looping, background, etc ... IDs for these properties are explained here : [Property Item Descriptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms534416(v=vs.85).aspx)